# Connect dbslim with Fitnesse

Tags: jdbc, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I'm trying to connect to a database from Fitnesse, but it keeps giving an error message.
I'm using dbslim of MarkFink:
https://github.com/markfink/dbslim

the message I keep getting is:
Could not invoke constructor for DbSlimSetup

this is my current page:

```
!contents -R2 -g -p -f -h

!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim} 

!*> setup
|import|
|fitnesse.slim.test|
|fitnesse.fixtures|
|slim|

| script | Db Slim Setup |!-oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver-!| jdbc:oracle:thin:@host_name:1521:database_name | username | password |
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you did not include the dbslim jar / or the path to the generated `.class` files into your classpath when invoking test. Try putting in something like below on the test page (or actually anywhere on the path of your test case)

`!path /the/path/to/your/project/output`

The path is the place that your generated `.class` files will go if you directly include source code of Db Slim; if you built it as a jar, use the path to the jar.

To explain this a little bit, FitNesse will invoke the actual test system in the runtime, or in another word, the test cases are running on a seperate process than the FitNesse webserver itself. By default, FitNesse will only include `fitnesse.jar` in the classpath of the invoked process. When you call `!path`, you actually include the path to the accumulated classpath of the invoked process. You can find out more on `!path` [here](http://butunclebob.com/FitNesse.UserGuide.ClassPath)

Comment: note the way you specify path will be different on windows machine.